# Add string suffixes of string file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've array values to which I want to add some suffixes:

```
var arr = ["folder1/1.jpg","folder2/2.png","foldern/some.jpg"];
```

Adding prefix *'_thumb'* should result this:

```
newArr = ["folder1/1_thumb.jpg","folder2/2_thumb.png","foldern/some_thumb.jpg"];
```

This is my code but not good:

```
var arr = ["folder1/1.jpg", "folder2/2.png", "foldern/some.jpg"];
  var newArr = [];
  arr.forEach(image => {
    var onlyPath = path.dirname(image);
    var filename = path.basename(image).split('.');
    newArr.push(onlyPath + '/' + filename[0] + '_thumb' + '.' + filename[1]);
  });
  console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: Show us what you tried so far …

Comment: Regex is the key, share your code.

Comment: in case the filename containe a dot in its path, your code will not work.

Comment: Sorry, I using `var path = require('path')` of nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the Array.map

```js
let arr = ["folder1/1.jpg","folder2/2.png","foldern/some.jpg"];
let newArr = arr.map(img => img.split('.').join('_thumb.'));
console.log(newArr)
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake, i did not see there is a different suffix, I will correct it.

Answer (score 1):

**This one perfectly works if you have different extensions in your array (e.g. .png, .jpeg, etc.)**

1. Call each element of the array.
2. Split the current element with respect to the dot(".").
3. Concatinate the desired string ("_thumb") between the array result of splitted element.

```js
var arr = ["folder1/1.jpg","folder2/2.png","foldern/some.jpg"];
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      var splitted_string = arr[i].split(".");
      arr[i] = splitted_string[0]+"_thumb."+splitted_string[1];
      console.log(arr[i]);
    }
```

Comment: @TinhNQ try this one :)

Comment: try if it works with this 
'var arr = ["folder1/1.1.jpg","folder2/image.2.png","foldern/some.image.jpg"];'

Comment: Well @InslemIT that would be simple. If that's the case, then use the lastIndexOf().

Comment: The it would exactly split the string at the dot before the extenxion

Answer (score 1):

use this:

```js
  var arr = ["folder1/1.jpg","folder2/2.png","foldern/some.jpg"];
      var newArr = [];
      arr.forEach(filename => {
        var name = filename.split('.').slice(0, -1).join('.')+'_thumb.'+filename.split('.').pop();
        newArr.push(name);
        console.log('name ',name );
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 arr.map(function(el) {
  return el.replace(/\./g,"_thumb.")
})
```

Comment: handle the png too, you're so close :p

Answer (score 1):

Use [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split). Its simple. Phew ;)

```js
let arr = ["folder1/1.jpg","folder2/2.png","foldern/some.jpg"];
let newArr = arr.map(img => img.split('.')[0] + '_thumb.' + img.split('.')[1]);
console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

The below given code can help you. It inserts the given ("_thumb") string before the ".xxx" extension

```
//function to run
function test()
    {
      var arr = ["folder1/1.jpg","folder2/2.png","foldern/some.jpg"];
      var newArr=[];

      for(i in arr)
      {
      //gets the index of "." sign to add the "_thumb" string before it
      var pos=arr[i].indexOf(".");
      var newVal=insert(arr[i], pos, "_thumb");
      newArr.push(newVal);

      }

    }

    //inserts the given string ("_thumb") between the array value
    function insert(str, index, value) {
        return str.substr(0, index) + value + str.substr(index);
    }
```